# Pass parameter to SQL query in a file

Tags: sql-server, shell, parameters

I have the following query (call it queryA):

```
Select * from TableA where FieldA in ('foo', 'bar')
```

I would like to write a (shell?) script file something like:

```
execute queryA take parameter values from ParamFileA write output to OutputFileA
```

Where ParamFileA would contain `('foo', 'bar')`

Is it possible? This is for SQL Server.

Comment: Did you try something? It looks similiar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010612/tsql-string-modify)

Comment: @lad2025 Thank you, it looks like your link is about manipulating format of parameters, I am curious how to pass parameters from the file.

Comment: Which shell PowerShell/CMD? It is as simple as build query + read file + concatenate to query values for in + execute it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you took a look at sqlcmd? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx

Comment: For really simple things doing this with .bat & sqlcmd might work, but for anything that requires more complex parameters, output formatting or error handling I would use a script language.

Comment: In case of sqlcmd, how do I pass a file which contains list of parameters?

Comment: What type of shell? Windows?

Comment: @CalebMauer, yes, CMD

Comment: See my answer, I think it will at least get you started. But really, you'd be better off using PowerShell, VBScript, Python, something like that instead. Windows bat files are only for people like me, operating in environments where getting new software installed is difficult and not all script users have admin rights. If you can use sharper tools for this I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a .bat file with the following content (read the REM comments for details):

```
REM This script expects these parameters: Path of file with query to run, path of file with parameters, path of file to save output in.
set SQLFILE=%1
set PARAMFILE=%2
SET OUTPUTFILE=%3

SET TEMPFILEPATH=C:\Temp\tempsqlstatementt.sql

REM Combine SQL command and parameters into one temporary file.
copy /B %SQLFILE% + %PARAMFILE% %TEMPFILEPATH%

REM Execute combined SQL command and write to specified output
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\Temp\tempsqlstatementt.sql -o %OUTPUTFILE%

REM Cleanup the temp file.
DEL %TEMPFILEPATH% /F /Q
```

You can call this bat file like this:

```
ExecuteWithParams QueryFile ParamFile OutputFile
```

Here it is again but I put in actual file paths:

```
C:\Users\You\>ExecuteWithParams.bat QueryFile.sql ParamFile.sql OutputFile.txt
```

Also, if sqlcmd isn't on the [path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) you'll have to put the path to sqlcmd into the bat file.